# Update Combo Chart Title Dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, charts, combo-chart

I have a combo chart, but I couldn't change the title of the combo chart dynamically, but when I change the chart to a column chart or line chart, the title successfully changes but not with the combo chart.

Here is the code I used to change the title dynamically

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newtitle = sheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();

  var charts = sheet.getCharts()[3];
  var chart = charts.modify()
    .setOption('title', newtitle)
    .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart)

}
```

The title of the chart will change depending on the text written/chosen from **var newtitle = sheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();**

Hope someone can help with the code. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, unfortunately, it seemed that the title cannot be directly changed. When your showing script is run, an error like `Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ###.` occurs. So, in my case, I used a workaround. How about the following workaround?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var newtitle = sheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[3]; // 4th chart in the active sheet is used.
  var chartId = chart.getChartId();
  var chartObj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), { ranges: [sheet.getSheetName()], fields: "sheets.charts" }).sheets[0].charts.find(c => c.chartId == chartId);
  var series = chartObj.spec.basicChart.series.reduce((o, { type }, i) => (o[i] = { type }, o), {});
  var updatedChart = chart.modify().setOption('title', newtitle).setOption('series', series).build();
  sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
}
```

- When this script is run, the title of the combo chart of `var chart = sheet.getCharts()[3]` is changed.

#### Note:

- This is my workaround. I think that there might also be other approaches. So, this is just one workaround.

### Added:

As another approach, how about modifying the title using Sheets API as follows?

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var newtitle = sheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[3]; // 4th chart in the active sheet is used.
  var chartId = chart.getChartId();
  var { spec } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [sheet.getSheetName()], fields: "sheets.charts" }).sheets[0].charts.find(c => c.chartId == chartId);
  spec.title = newtitle;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ updateChartSpec: { chartId, spec } }] }, ssId);
}
```

Comment: When using your code, the combo chart title still has not changed. 

The script highlights this as an issue
myFunction @
Chart Title:10

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. About `When using your code, the combo chart title still has not changed.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my script using a combo chart, I confirmed the title was changed. I apologize for my poor skill. So, in this case, it is required to know your actual situation. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating `When using your code, the combo chart title still has not changed.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel And, I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The script highlights this as an issue myFunction @ Chart Title:10`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyALo_tE_75w1SCPCIiiqgToyYRAnZJKMdpBpW6G5mY/edit#gid=1949705865

Here is the sheet @Tanaike

Comment: Sorry,  here is the detail of an error i received when using your script

`Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1CyALo_tE_75w1SCPCIiiqgToyYRAnZJKMdpBpW6G5mY.
myFunction @ Chart Title.gs:10`

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChartId')
myFunction2 @ Chart Title.gs:7`

Another error i received

Comment: Sorry my mistake, your added code works fine. Thank you @Tanaike. Sorry for the inconvenience